# TLSharp exception during reading messages from chat

Tags: c#, telegram

I use the following code for reading new messages from Telegram chat:

```
    public async Task GatherChatHistory(string channelName, string ch_id, string mid, int offset = 0, int minId = 0, int maxId = -1, int limit = 100)
    {
        Log.Info(Tag, "In GatherChatHistory Start");
        TelegramClient client = CreateClient();
        await InitializeAndAuthenticateClient(client);

        int maximal = Convert.ToInt32(mid);

        Log.Info(Tag, "In GatherChatHistory Before GetUserDialogAsync");

        try
        {
            var dialogs = (TLDialogs)await client.GetUserDialogsAsync();
            var chat = dialogs.chats.lists
                .OfType<TLChat>()
                .FirstOrDefault(c => c.title == channelName);

            Log.Info(Tag, "In GatherChatHistory After GetUserDialogAsync " + (chat != null));

            if (chat != null)
            {
                Log.Info(Tag, "Chat != null, " + channelName);
                try
                {
                    var tlAbsMessages =
                        await client.GetHistoryAsync(
                            new TLInputPeerChat { chat_id = chat.id }, offset,
                            minId, maxId, limit);
                    Log.Info(Tag, "After GetHistoryAsync");

                    var tlChannelMessages = (TLMessages)tlAbsMessages;
                    Log.Info(Tag, "GatherChatHistory Messages count = " + (tlChannelMessages.messages.lists.Count - 1));

                    for (var index = 0; index < tlChannelMessages.messages.lists.Count - 1; index++)
                    {
                        var tlAbsMessage = tlChannelMessages.messages.lists[index];
                        Log.Info(Tag, "Message Type = " + tlAbsMessage.GetType());
                        if (tlAbsMessage.GetType().ToString().Equals("TeleSharp.TL.TLMessageService"))
                            continue;
                        var message = (TLMessage)tlAbsMessage;

                        if (message.id == maximal)
                        {
                            Log.Info(Tag, "GatherChatHistory Chat_id = " + channelName + " maximal was reached");
                            break;
                        }
                        if (message.id <= maximal)
                        {
                            Log.Info(Tag, "GatherChatHistory Chat_id = " + channelName + " message.id = " + message.id + " maxid = " + maximal);
                            continue;
                        }

                        if (message.media == null)
                        {
                            Log.Info(Tag, "Message ID = " + message.id);
                            Log.Info(Tag, "Chat ID = " + chat.id);
                            Log.Info(Tag, "Content = " + message.message);
                            await AddNewMessageToDatabase(channelName, ch_id, message.message, null, message.from_id.GetValueOrDefault(), message.id);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            switch (message.media.GetType().ToString())
                            {
                                case "TeleSharp.TL.TLMessageMediaPhoto":
                                    var tLMessageMediaPhoto = (TLMessageMediaPhoto)message.media;
                                    var photo = (TLPhoto)tLMessageMediaPhoto.photo;
                                    var photoSize = photo.sizes.lists.OfType<TLPhotoSize>().Last();
                                    TLFileLocation tf = (TLFileLocation)photoSize.location;
                                    var resFile = await client.GetFile(new TLInputFileLocation
                                    {

                                        local_id = tf.local_id,
                                        secret = tf.secret,
                                        volume_id = tf.volume_id
                                    },               0);

                                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(resFile.bytes))
                                    {
                                        byte[] byteArr = ms.ToArray();
                                        string base64image = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArr);
                                        Log.Info(Tag, "Caption = " + tLMessageMediaPhoto.caption);
                                        Log.Info(Tag, "Base64 Image = " + base64image);
                                        await AddNewMessageToDatabase(channelName, ch_id, tLMessageMediaPhoto.caption, base64image, message.from_id.GetValueOrDefault(), message.id);
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "TeleSharp.TL.TLMessageMediaDocument":
                                    var tLMessageMediaDocument = (TLMessageMediaDocument)message.media;
                                    break;
                                case "TeleSharp.TL.TLMessageMediaWebPage":
                                    var tLMessageMediaWebPage = (TLMessageMediaWebPage)message.media;
                                    string url = string.Empty;
                                    if (tLMessageMediaWebPage.webpage.GetType().ToString() != "TeleSharp.TL.TLWebPageEmpty")
                                    {
                                        var webPage = (TLWebPage)tLMessageMediaWebPage.webpage;
                                        url = webPage.url;
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Logger.Error("Telegram Chat History exception: " + e.Message);
                    Log.Error(Tag, "Telegram Chat History exception: " + e.Message);
                    Log.Error(Tag, "Telegram Chat History StackTrace = " + e.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
                Log.Info(Tag, "Chat == null");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(Tag, "ReadUserAsync Error : " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

I check chat for new messages one time per minute. I don't have any problems with text messages, all of them I read without any problem. Also I can read one photo, but only one per time. If in chat there are more than one photo or photo and text messages after reading photo TLSharp throws exception:

```
[MessagingService:TelegramBridge] Telegram Chat History exception: msg_seqno 
too low (the server has already received a message with a lower msg_id but 
with either a higher or an equal and odd seqno)
[MessagingService:TelegramBridge] Telegram Chat History StackTrace = 
System.InvalidOperationException: msg_seqno too low (the server has already 
received a message with a lower msg_id but with either a higher or an equal 
and odd seqno)
[MessagingService:TelegramBridge]   at 
TLSharp.Core.Network.MtProtoSender.HandleBadMsgNotification (System.UInt64 
messageId, System.Int32 sequence, System.IO.BinaryReader messageReader) 
[0x0009f] in <24dee86ac15149c89ccf3cac229b439d>:0 
[MessagingService:TelegramBridge]   at 
TLSharp.Core.Network.MtProtoSender.processMessage (System.UInt64 messageId, 
System.Int32 sequence, System.IO.BinaryReader messageReader, 
TeleSharp.TL.TLMethod request) [0x00182] in 
<24dee86ac15149c89ccf3cac229b439d>:0 
[MessagingService:TelegramBridge]   at TLSharp.Core.Network.MtProtoSender+
<Receive>d__9.MoveNext () [0x000bb] in <24dee86ac15149c89ccf3cac229b439d>:0
```

Can anybody help me with this problem?

**UPD**
I localize the place of the error:

```
    var resFile = await client.GetFile(new TLInputFileLocation
                                    {

                                        local_id = tf.local_id,
                                        secret = tf.secret,
                                        volume_id = tf.volume_id
                                    },               0);
```

but I still don't know what to do...
**UPD**
This is main function:

```
        async Task<int> WriteMessagesFromChannels()
    {
        Log.Info(Tag, "In WriteMessagesFromChannels");
        var url = "http://" + MainActivity.Host + ":" + MainActivity.Port + MainActivity.Url + "/groups?page=1&pageSize=10000";
        Log.Info(Tag, "URL = " + url);
        var json = FetchServerData(url);
        if (json == null)
        {
            Log.Info(Tag, "In WriteMessagesFromChannels: JSON = NULL");
            return -1;
        }
        var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
        var groups = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TelegramChannel[]>(obj["data"]["items"].ToString());
        Log.Info(Tag, "In WriteMessagesFromChannels: size = " + groups.Length);
        if (groups != null)
        {
            foreach (var gr in groups)
            {
                Log.Info(Tag, "Group name = " + gr.name + ", monitor = " + gr.monitor);
                if (gr.ischannel == true || gr.monitor == false)
                    continue;
                string maxid = ReadMaxId(gr.id);
                if (maxid == "")
                    continue;
                Log.Info(Tag, "In WriteMessagesFromChannels: MAXID = " + maxid);
                await ReadMessagesFromChat(gr.name, gr.id, maxid);
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
            Log.Info(Tag, "In WriteMesasagesFromChannels: CYCLE IS FINISHED");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.Info(Tag, "In WriteMessagesFromChannels: GROUPS = NULL");
        }
        return 1;
    }

    async Task<int> ReadMessagesFromChat(string name, string ch_id, string maxid)
    {
        Log.Info(Tag, "In ReadMessagesFromChat");
        //await bridge.GetPhotoFromChannel(name);
        await bridge.GatherChatHistory(name, ch_id, maxid);
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Where is new chat.id defined? : TLInputPeerChat { chat_id = chat.id }, offset,  You are only getting the first : var chat = dialogs.chats.lists
                .OfType<TLChat>()
                .FirstOrDefault(c => c.title == channelName);

Comment: It is not a problem at that moment. My test channes has unical name and I see that I receive messages from it. Problem with reading pictures

Comment: Read the exception.  The issue is with msg_id.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand why... And this is happened with images only, I normally read several text messages

Comment: Yes I do. TCP datagrams are max size of ~1500 bytes.  Text message are usually small at are in one datagram.  Pictures are large and require lots of datagrams.  Just because text are working doesn't imply that the id is correct.

Comment: So you think that all my problems because of the wrong id?

Comment: I just know what the exception states.  There isn't enough code posted to determine root cause at this time.

Comment: I can send you telegram part of my application if you give me your email.

Comment: It probably won't help without debug info.  It is better that you isolate issue and I will help if you can't figure out the root cause.

Comment: How I can isolate it? I'm working with C# and Telegram two monthes only...

Comment: Add break points and step through code or add some print statements to help find issue.

Comment: If I only know what to seek for...